# Inline specifier

Tags: c++, inline

I've been reading about inline functions in C++ on *[Inline Functions in C++](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/)*.

My questions are:

1. Does an inline function increase the size of the code?
2. What kind of functions are suitable for inlining?
3. How does it compare to an [ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler)? If yes, then what is the difference between inline and ISR?

Comment: ISR's have nothing to do with inlined funcitons, these are orthogonal things.

Comment: I mean in functionality, what understood from the link is that inline are specified for small very quick functions. So I think they are similar to ISRs in functionality.

Comment: _"So I think they are similar to ISRs in functionality."_ No.

Comment: inlining is mostly for ODR. As compiler may choose to inline or not inline function with or without the keyword.

Comment: ISR, is that *Incoherent Scatter Radar* , or *Initial State Radiation*

Comment: The site seems to be really outdated.

Comment: The explanations on that site seems to be mostly plain wrong. Possibly contributed by other newbies, and a long time ago. For example the rules about when a function can and cannot be inlined looks like the state 20 years ago. You shouldn't believe much of what you read there.

Comment: Since C++17 the meaning of `inline` has changed and it now allows for functions to be defined in multiple translation units without an ODR violation, as long as the definitions are the same. This allows for implementations in header files. Modern compilers decide if a function is to be inlined by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ Super FAQ Inline function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf) says that:

> **inline functions might make it larger:** This is the notion of code bloat, as described above. For example, if a system has 100 inline
>   functions each of which expands to 100 bytes of executable code and is
>   called in 100 places, that’s an increase of 1MB. Is that 1MB going to
>   cause problems? Who knows, but it is possible that that last 1MB could
>   cause the system to “thrash,” and that could slow things down.
>
> **inline functions might make it smaller:** The compiler often generates more code to push/pop registers/parameters than it would by
>   inline-expanding the function’s body. This happens with very small
>   functions, and it also happens with large functions when the optimizer
>   is able to remove a lot of redundant code through procedural
>   integration — that is, when the optimizer is able to make the large
>   function small.

2. Compilers are so smart so that they automatically perform inlining. `inline` is just a hint to the compiler which compiler is not required to obey.
3. `inline` keyword has nothing to do with ISR.

Comment: I would add that `inline` can be used to get around the [ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). It's probably the most common reason (if not the only reason) to use it with modern compilers.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes as it tells the compiler it can replace the function definitions wherever those are being called.

2) When performance is needed, when the overhead of the function calls is too important compare to the function's job. It is well explained in cplusplus.com :

> A normal function call instruction is encountered, the program stores
>   the memory address of the instructions immediately following the
>   function call statement, loads the function being called into the
>   memory, copies argument values, jumps to the memory location of the
>   called function, executes the function codes, stores the return value
>   of the function, and then jumps back to the address of the instruction
>   that was saved just before executing the called function. Too much run
>   time overhead.

3) I can't see any link between inline and ISR functions.